# When user types into HTML <input/> where is that data stored?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I am writing a jQuery script that needs to work with an existing unchangeable plugin. This plugin listens for text being typed into an `<input type='text'>` and then processes the result. I can't alter this. My script is setting the text of the input via `$('#display).val(newValue);` as a jQueryUI Slider is dragged. I need the plugin to recognize this value as being typed by the user so that it processes the `newValue` as the slider is dragged.

Can anyone point me in the write direction for this?

Comment: Do you have the plug-in code? We would need to see what event the plug-in has hooked so that you could fire it in your code. Generally plug-ins hook the change() event and so setting the value like you are doing would work.

Comment: Agree with Bill... Need to see some code first; we can't guess the name of the plugin or the code it contains.

Comment: The code is obsfucated - I will try post some soon though. If we assume it is listening for change() or keyup etc how can I simulate these events?

Comment: $('#display').change() or $('#display').keyup()

Comment: In real javascript its just `inputElement.value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to 'trigger' the keyup (or keypressed?) event so that the event handler is fired.

Here is one (slightly dirty) way to do it:

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keyup");
e.which = 50; // # Some key code value
$("#display").trigger(e);
```

Note that the plugin may be looking for particular keys, and I may have guessed the event wrong.

The more sophisticated way to do it would be to track down the plugin's event handler, and then invoke it directly. FireBug may help you find it by step-through debugging. Otherwise, you can use jquery to start inspecting the input's event handlers.

```
var events = $('#display').data("events");
jQuery.each(events, function(key, handlerObj) {
  console.log(handlerObj); // alert(handlerObj);
});
```

Once you've found the relevant handler, you can invoke it directly.

HTH

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much, your first solution works perfectly! I love this site!

Answer (score 1):

You have to put an Onchange listener to the text field and trigger the necessary function to listen to onchange values of the user. eg: 
function func(){.....put your logic.....}

If you are looking at reading value from a text field on changing a slider, then you have to put the necessary function on the slider control.